# Change CSS property of one div based on element in another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, jquery-selectors

I need to change the css propery of left div if right div doesn't contain image.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pg-left-bar"></div>
    <div class="pg-right-bar">
        <img src="img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paycb/1/

If right div has no image then left div width should be change to 100% and margin removed from left div and change the display property of right div to `none`

I know how to change the css property using jquery only if i am looking for the element in same div

`$('.pg-right-bar').has('img').css({ 'background-color': '#fff' });`

But i am not sure how i can do this for the above senario.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE

Jquery Code to achive this

```
if ( $('.pg-right-bar').has('img').length > 0 )
{
    $('.pg-left-bar').css({ 'background-color': '#ccc' });

}
else
{
     $('.pg-left-bar').css({ 'margin-right': '0px' });
     $('.pg-left-bar').css({ 'width': '100%' });
     $('.pg-right-bar').css({ 'display': 'none' });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paycb/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/paycb/2/

**JS**

```
if ( $('.pg-right-bar').has('img').length > 0 )
    $('.pg-left-bar').css({ 'background-color': '#fff' });
```

jQuery selectors limit the amount of selected elements. Using `has()` limits the object count in this case to `0` if no `img`-tag is available.
As far as I know this scenario cannot be solved with pure CSS. I gave you an example in JS.

Comment: I did it based on your reply http://jsfiddle.net/paycb/4/, Please check if this approach is correct.

Comment: Looks and work fine for me. I provided a sample and had no doubt you could write the `else` part :-)